# Query in database with join in drupal

Tags: drupal, join

This code not working

```
$var = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'tt')
  ->fields('tt', array('name'))
  ->join('my_table', 'dd', 'tt.tid = dd.my_field')
  ->execute()
```

But next code working normally.

```
$var = db_query('SELECT name FROM taxonomy_term_data tt JOIN my_table dd ON tt.tid = dd.my_field')
```

where went my wrong?

Comment: Make sure you use the top db_select syntax instead of direct query statement to avoid SQL Injection attacks.. It temping given how complicated the db_select syntax can be when joining tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`join()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Ajoin/7) isn't chain-able, use

```
$query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'tt')->fields('tt', array('name'));
$query->join('my_table', 'dd', 'tt.tid = dd.my_field');
$var = $query->execute()
```